# How do I setup .htacess so it does not give me a error. (Noob)

Tags: wamp

I am new with all this Wamp stuff. I don't get how to rewrite.
All I want is to be able to access my /www and not get a error.

> [Fri Mar 07 19:25:40.022309 2014] [core:error] [pid 8152:tid 1512]
>   [client 127.0.0.1:59246] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10
>   internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/dash
>
> [Fri Mar 07 19:25:41.019366 2014] [core:error] [pid 8152:tid 1532] [client 127.0.0.1:59251] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10
>   internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
>   http://localhost/tplayers

My .htaccess is,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
Options  -MultiViews
```

And my hosts are

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 192.168.0.150
```

Please help me? I've been looking for a solution for the past hour.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: You shouldn't be creating lines like `127.0.0.1 192.168.0.150`, the second entry should be a domain name, not an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosts file is incorrect and probably what is causing the redirects error.

A valid hosts file entry gives a name to an ip address so you can use the name rather than the ip address in your browser etc. It is in fact an early method of doing what DNS servers do for us all now.

So a vaid host file would be something like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.150 fred.dev
```

I am not sure what you were trying to do with the line `127.0.0.1 192.168.0.150` but if `192.168.0.150` is your actual internal network ip address then that would explain the redirect loop.

To reset/refresh the DNS Cache after you change the hosts file, you will either have to reboot or do this from a command line:-

```
net stop "DNS Client"
net start "DNS Client"
```

I am no expert on url rewrite, but its possible there is actually nothing wrong with your rewrite rules.